# Bluetooth SPP to a Raspberry returns looping weird values

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, barcode-scanner, spp

I'm running out of ideas, I finally got a connection to a Bluetooth Barcode Scanner via SPP, but once I'm listening to the connection with

```
sudo cat /dev/rfcomm0
```

It's repeating the scanned code, everytime prepending some ^JJJ values:

```
^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766

^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766

^^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766

^J^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766

^^J^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766

J^^J^J^JJ^JJJJ^J^4000539103766
```

and this continues, sometimes till it stop by itself or till I kill it.

Anyone has ever seen this?

Comment: Is `^j` the linefeed control character? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character.

Comment: Ah - ok, good to know. Wondering why the scanner sends this so often then. Thank you for the tip!